# Angular 2 Ionic Form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to submit a form in angular using ionic

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="https://localhost:44370/Account/ExternalLogin">
    <div>
        <p>
            <!-- ion-button block [disabled]="isDisabled" -->
            <button 
                name="provider" value="Coinbase" type="submit"
                title="Log in using your Coinbase account">
                Coinbase
            </button>               
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when I click the submit button nothing occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ngForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view) (template or reactive way) provided by angular. Also for you button create it twice, one with invalid and other with valid form state.

use `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"`

```
<form #form method="post" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal" action="https://localhost:44370/Account/ExternalLogin">
    <div>
        <p>
            <button ion-button block [disabled]="isDisabled" type="submit" title="Log in using your Coinbase account">
                Coinbase
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="provider" value="Coinbase">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

P.D.: It's wise to always valite the data you want to submit programatically to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: Answer looks good, please make sure to vote on any resources you've used to make it ;)