# POST form answers into externar API ionic angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send a simple form answer to an external API using ionic.

1- First, I tried with the way I tought was the standard

```html
<form action="www.api.com" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="bar">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But when I click "Submit", nothing happens.

2- Then, I've tried using ngForm as answered in this question [angular 2 ionic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54338220/angular-2-ionic-form).

```html
<form #form method="post" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal" action="https://localhost:44370/Account/ExternalLogin">
    <div>
        <p>
            <button ion-button block [disabled]="isDisabled" type="submit" title="Log in using your Coinbase account">
                Coinbase
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="provider" value="Coinbase">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

But it said

> Runtime error
>
> _co.onSubmit is not a function

So I created it in the .ts

```js
onSubmit() {
    console.log('We are in function onSubmit');
    this.http.post(this.requesturl, postData);
  }
```

But the problem now is how do I obtain the data that the user put in the fields?

Which is the correct approach to this problem? What do I need to do to simply send a form to an external API?

I'm new to Angular and Ionic, so I don't know the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `method="post"` isn't required.

Add `#form="ngForm"` and replace `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"` with `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"` like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
```

and you will receive the data that user puts in the input fields in `postData` param:

```
onSubmit(postData:any) {
    console.log(postData);
    this.http.post(this.requesturl, postData);
}
```

Comment: Now I tried with <form #form action={{requesturl}} (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" > in the form and onSubmit(postData:any) {
    console.log('We are in function onSubmit');
    console.log(postData);
  }

in the .ts.  I'm still getting the "undefined" in console.log(postData)

Comment: @Birivera Sorry I forgot to mention `#form="ngForm"`. Please try with this.

Comment: @Birivera Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

check out working Example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqqy3p)

place it your `component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('We are in function onSubmit');

  }
}
```

Comment: In that example, we are calling the method (that is working), but we aren't actually sending anything and that's the part I don't know how to do.